# Запрос в SqLite по дате

Tags: java, android

String date = дата 06/05/2018
а по запросу я хочу получить данные только по месяцам и году... 
Храню по датам, так как идет сортировка данных по датам.. а отображение по месячно.
Как правильно сдеть запрос

В базе данных храню в типом text.
То есть, надо писать функцию для SqLite, и я не уверен,можно ли для не писать.

Логика такая в бд хранится данные типа text, 06/05/2018. 
Я хочу поймать данные к примеру 05/2018 без даты.

```
 public Cursor ReaderWithDateBaseLite(Context context,String date){
    this.dbHelper = new MySQLiteOpenHelper (context);
    db = this.dbHelper.getWritableDatabase ();
    this.c = db.query (dbHelper.tableGeneral,new String[]{"_id","summa","description","nameCoast"},  "date LIKE ?", new String[]{"%"+date+"%"}, null, null, null, null);

    return this.c;
   }
```

Comment: Попробуйте использовать в условии 'between' а в параметры передавать начало и конец месяца

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Не  понятно в каком формате хранится дата в sql, но если в таком же dd/mm/yyyy, то вырезаешь из string date последние 4 символа как год и сравниваешь.

```
    String date = "06/05/2018";
    String year = date.substring(6, 9);
    .....

    this.c = db.query (dbHelper.tableGeneral,new String[]{"_id","summa","description","nameCoast"},  "date LIKE ?", new String[]{"%"+year}, null, null, null, null);
```